# How can I compact a huge sqlite file containing huge blob?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, sqlite

I have an over 300m sqlite file which is just impractical in my app.

I was wondering if there is a way to compact it in order to make it smaller for downloading from the app store and then extract it on first launch.

Comment: ok for the edit... just hope the old blog datatype != file system discussion is not coming up...

Comment: Yes, you can compress it with [ZLIB](http://www.zlib.net/) or something similar.

Comment: (Though it might be better to compress the blob before you insert it into the DB.)

Comment: What kind of data is going into the DB? My app has images and videos so I simply put a filename into the DB so the DB stays relatively small. When removing entries, I make sure to remove the appropriate files too.

Comment: There is the vacuum command. Watch out for rowIDs being reset tho.